# What is the name of the mountains/hills northwest of Secomber?

Tags: forgotten-realms, maps

What is the name of this mountain/hill chain, northwest of Secomber? I can't seem to find any information on them, much less their name.

[image: A map excerpt showing the area east of Waterdeep, centered on a hills/mountain region that is not labelled.]
<sup>*Map excerpt from free map of NW Faerûn [published by WotC](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/map-faer%C3%BCn)*</sup>

Comment: Could you source the map image?

Comment: Found the map here: http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/map-faer%C3%BCn

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Scourge of the Sword Coast](http://my-realms.blogspot.com.au/2014/02/scourge-of-sword-coast-0-not-quite.html) includes a detailed (and well labelled) map of the area - which tells us the hills in question are called **The Forlorn Hills**.

*(Copies of the map, either digital or poster-print, can be bought from the artist/cartographer [Mike Schley](http://prints.mikeschley.com/p530730153/e2c5cd88f). The D&D Next adventure can be bought from [DMs Guild](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/125600/Dreams-of-the-Red-Wizards-Scourge-of-the-Sword-Coast-DD-Next).)*

---

[*Princes of the Apocalypse*](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/princes-apocalypse) takes place in the Dessarin Valley, to the north of the Forlorn Hills - they appear on the southern edge of the [area map](http://prints.mikeschley.com/p763166286/h1c53b7b4#h1c53b7b4).

---

A less detailed, but still well-labelled, map can be seen at the [Forgotten Realms Wiki](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_Coast_North).

And another can be found in the pages of the free Web Enhancement download for [*City of Splendors: Waterdeep*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060503a).

Comment: There is a highly detailed map of the entirety of the Realms available to download from this thread: [link](http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=13515&whichpage=10)

Answer (score 3):

As other users said, they're the Forlorn Hills, while Marco Volo also states:

> Well-learned folk know the [Crumbling] Stair to be a ruin that stands in what some call "the Sword Hills," a lawless, brigand-infested hill country east of Waterdeep, betwixt Ardeep Forest and Uluvin

This is in "*The Adventures of Volo - the Crumbling Stair"* by Ed Greenwood, I believe it's in Dragon #275.